# Facebook, move photos to a group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-photos

I already have some photos posted, quite a lot. As my group of 'friends' has grown I only have created a group for close friends and family. I now want to only show this group some of the photos - so :

- can I move the photos to the group?
  or
- can I restrict the photos I have already uploaded to just that group?

I realise there is a 'subscriptions' facility now so I don't have to add new aquaintances to friends

Comment: It is not possible to move the album photos to group. Album photos is always public,you can make them private one by one.

Answer (score 1):

- *Moving* the photos would just mean deleting them from the original album and reuploading them. There is no way to move them directly.
- You can change the privacy of the album and choose a *Friend List*, but not a *Group*.

So the best (only) bet you have is to delete them and reupload.